# Access a Docker's container subdomain

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, subdomain, hosts

Let's say I have a container `service-1` on the same network as another service `service-2` described in my `docker-compose.yml`. I can therefore access `service-1` from `service-2` requesting `http://service-1`.

What about accessing a subdomain of `service-1` ? Is there an easy way to do it ?

I would like to modify the `hosts` file of the machine but since I do not know the IP of the `service-1` container it doesn't seem to be the right solution.

Thank you

Comment: Time has passed... And no one ever answered this :o